# vectorizing code in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save, vectorization

I have an ASCII file containing a number of surfaces created in a seismic interpretation software. They are a family of interpolated surfaces between a top surface and a bottom surface are a family All surfaces are sampled at each point of a regular squuare grid.
The file structure is:
X Y Z1 Z2.....Zn
Where X, Y are coordinate vectors common to all surfaces, Z1, Z2,...,Zn are the surfaces.
I would like to import the file in Matlab and save each individual surface to its own file XYZ.

Assuming the data is imported and stored in variable "data", this code does the job:

```
r=size(data,1);
c=size(data,2)-2;
temp(:,1)=data(:,1);
temp(:,2)=data(:,2);
for i = 1:c
    temp(:,3)=data(:,i+2);
    tempname = ['proportional_',num2str(i*5-5),'ms','.txt']; % naming reflects the 
                                                           % fact that surfaces
                                                           % are in two way travel
                                                           % time and that median 
                                                           % distance between each
                                                           % two surfaces is ~ 5 
                                                           % milliseconds
    save (tempname,'temp','-ASCII','-TABS'); 
end                                                                                                                                                                   
clear r c temp tempname i
clc
```

I would like to vectorize this code by taking as much of it as possible out of the for loop. I think that doing it for the save command may not be possible, but perhaps the other 2 lines can. My feeling is I should use cell arrays or perhaps structures, but I can't think of the right syntax.
Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: If you have a n-D array, `data` with the format: `X Y Z1 Z2...` does it zero pad the `X` and `Y` vectors at the end since `Z*` will always have `numel(X)*numel(Y)` values?

Comment: I   am not sure I understand the question. data is a 2D array where each of X, Y, Z1,....,Zn is a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
temp = arrayfun( @(x) data(:,[1 2 x]), 3:size(data,2), 'UniformOutput',0 );
arrayfun( @(x) dlmwrite( strcat('proportional_',num2str(x*5-5),'ms.txt'), ...
         temp{x}, '\t' ), 1:numel(temp) );
```

Comment: I will try this (and try to understand it as well) at the earliest opportunity. Will get back. Thanks!

Comment: Yowza.  +1 for ... well ... something.